# Using return value to put in another function's parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x

I couldn't find any source that had this problem so I'm really confused with no reference point for my code. Basically what I was trying to do is to get the return interest from get_interest_rate() and put it into the parentheses of get_interest(). I'm not too sure whether it's possible? I've been looking all over the Internet to try and find a source on how to do this but I can't find anything. Thank you!

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.account = "%d - %d - %d" %(a, b, c)
        self.balance = 0

    def get_account(self):
        print("Your account number is", self.account)
        return self.account

    def get_balance(self):
        print("You have %.2f" %self.balance)
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self):
        dep = float(input("Enter deposit amount: "))
        self.balance = self.balance + dep

    def withdraw(self):
        while True:
            draw = float(input("Enter withdrawal amount: "))
            if draw > self.balance:
                print("You have insufficient amount to withdraw")
                continue
            else:
                break
        self.balance = self.balance - draw
        print("You are left with %.2f" %self.balance)
        return self.balance

    def get_interest_rate(self):
        interest = 0
        if self.account[0] == '1':
            interest = 0.01
            print("Your interest rate is", interest)


       elif self.account[0] == '0':
            interest = 0.05
            print("Your interest rate is", interest)

        return interest

    def get_interest(self, interest):
        earned = self.balance * interest
        print("Your interest earned is %.2f" % earned)
        return earned


account1 = BankAccount(00, 12345, 11)
account1.get_account()
account1.deposit()
account1.get_balance()
account1.withdraw()
account1.get_interest_rate()
account1.get_interest()
```

So this is the output/error that I've been receiving:

```
Your interest rate is 0.05
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kovitan/PycharmProjects/Object-Oriented Programming/venv/Practical 2/Qn 4.py", line 51, in <module>
    account1.get_interest()
TypeError: get_interest() missing 1 required positional argument: 'interest'
```

Comment: If it's inside a class, do you need to pass it `self.interest`?

Comment: @G.Anderson No I do not need to pass it to self.interest, interest is just a standalone variable in get_interest_rate()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your code is clearly extracted from a class you failed to provide, and there is no main program: the line that elicits the error is missing.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't clear with my comment. If you don't have self.interest defined inside the class, you need to explicitly call `get_interest_rate` inside `get_interest()`, or you need to put the output of `get_interest_rate` into a variable (`x=get_interest_rate()`) that you can then pass into `get_interest()`, otherwise the function doesn't know what to use for the `interest` argument

Comment: @G.Anderson Yup, that worked for me  calling get_interest_rate() into get_interest(). Thank you!

Comment: `return print` makes no sense. `print` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @mkrieger1 ah I see, I'm just starting Python so I'm a little confused with Functions, Classes and Objects. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `account1.get_interest(..)` with the return of `account1.get_interest_rate()` type:

```
account1.get_interest(account1.get_interest_rate())
```

Comment: Ah, yes it worked! thank you! I'm a beginner at Python so I'm a little confused with classes and objects

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like these?.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.account = ['0']
        self.balance = balance

    def get_interest_rate(self):
        interest = 0
        if self.account[0] == '1':
            interest = 0.01
            print("Your interest rate is", interest)

        elif self.account[0] == '0':
            interest = 0.05
            print("Your interest rate is", interest)
        return interest

    def get_interest(self, interest):
        earned = self.balance * interest
        return "Your interest earned is %.2f" % earned


account = Account(1000)
print(account.get_interest(account.get_interest_rate()))
```

Comment: Haven't tried your method yet but I managed to with a minor fix to my code and it worked, thank you though!

Comment: No problem, I just add the parenthesis to the function call and remove the print in the return statement of the function. also, as you are using python 3, this link with help you to migrate from the python 2 format string syntax https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/